# Read triggers definition in PowerDesigner

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, powerdesigner

How to read triggers definition from database when use option "**Update Model from Database**" in PowerDesigner 16?

This option recognizes that I have new triggers in database and read them, but Definition field is empty. Inspecting dialog box for checking changes I have to apply to model, in section Triggers I have no options available.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: For SQL Server 2012, the trigger script is retrieved from sys.sql_modules.definition, which can be null if "encrypted", according to MS docs. Could it be the case?

Comment: No, definition is not null, I've already checked

Comment: Which exact version of PowerDesigner 16 are you using?

Comment: PowerDesigner version 16.5